# How does sorting work in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have this query: (Doctrine2 ODM)

```
    ....
->field('coordinates')
                ->near(
                (float)$lat,
                (float)$lng)
->field('date')
                ->lte($lastdate)
                ->sort('date','desc')
                ->limit(9)
                ->getQuery()
                ->execute()
                ->toArray();
```

It gives me documents with the following dates : (example)

```
2014-03-31 01:51:06
2014-03-31 01:51:02
2014-03-31 01:50:46
2014-03-31 01:50:07
```

IF I change the limit to 20 for example , I get these dates:

```
2014-03-31 01:52:01
2014-03-31 01:51:42
2014-03-31 01:51:16
2014-03-31 01:51:06
```

My question is why these dates were skipped in the first query ? 
Does mongoDB collects the first documents that match the criteria then sort them ? 
That would be very stupid !!

I changed the order in the query (criteria after sorting) but it doesn't seem to have any effect.. WTF

Comment: results are also sorted by distance , with $near , but that doesn't explain why newer docs are skipped when limit is low ... does it ?

Comment: what do you mean they sorted by distance? I can not see any code related to that.

Comment: I skipped that code and put "..."
I'll edit my code

Comment: this is strange. Mongo does not behave in the way you mentioned. Can you try the same thing without your near and see if the code behave in the similar wierd way. After this I would go to your mongoconsole and try to enter the bare mongo query which represents your Doctrine logic. May be doctrine is the culprit.

Comment: Without $near it seems ok , I think. 
Does $near disable the sorting effect ? does it have higher priority ?
because what seems happen is that , it get the 9 nearest docs then sort them by date, not combining the nearest and the newest..

Answer (score 0):

`$near` will get you the nearest documents; it's not going to get you newer documents further away.

From [the doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/):

> Specifies a point for which a geospatial query returns the closest documents first. The query sorts the documents from nearest to farthest.

`$near` without `$maxDistance` is inherently a sort; without specifying the bounds of the data you're interested in, applying a sort that superscedes the `$near` query would effectively negate the `$near`.

You might be able to combine a `$near` query that specifies both `$geometry` and `$maxDistance` to filter a result set, then `sort` to sort on the date of that filtered set, though. I haven't tried it, but it would change the semantics of your `$near` clause such that it may work.

Comment: I'm going to look for an implementation, It might take some time, I'm a newbie in MongoDB

Comment: I found out something about geopagination , but i don't seem to find the $mindistance attribute nor the minDistanc() method in doctrine, any idea?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/maxDistance/#op._S_maxDistance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort by distance, use $near, but if you want to sort by a different attribute, use [$within now $geoWithin](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) operator which returns results that are within a radius without sorting them, allowing you to sort on a different criteria.

Comment: I'm using this for pagination, now what I understand is that my logic is a bit wrong, because there might be newer documents but further, 
$lastdate is the oldest date of nearest document.
That might exclude newer documents.
Can you suggest how to use within for pagination ?

Comment: what are you paginating on? you can't sort on different things that are not correlated - either you sort by distance or by time.

Comment: exactly, This is the influence of "Elasticsearch", scoring concept..
I thought MongoDB would combine the sorting and give the best deal.

Comment: BTW I was paginating on the date

Comment: then use $within with sort on date.